# wx.ListCtrl with images (wxPython)

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I have wx.ListCtrl and I want to insert images (icons) to each item.

This is my code:

```
class ListView(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self,parent,size):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,-1,size=size)

    GameList = wx.ListCtrl(self,-1,pos=(20,20),size=(200,200))
    il = wx.ImageList(16,16)
    img_list=GameList.SetImageList(il, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)
    images=["joystick.png"]
    il.Add(wx.Bitmap(images[0]))

    index=GameList.InsertImageItem(0,0)
```

Somehow, it doesn't work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?  If so, please post those along with your question

Comment: well, im not getting error messages, it's just won't show the image. @wnnmaw

Comment: Is the image the right size? Also, I'm not sure if the list control handles PNGs out of the box. Did you try with JPEG?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing:

```
self.list.SetImageList(il, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)
```

In cases like this it is always a good idea to look at the wxPython demo:)